# Why are threads created with message queues?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, message-queue

This is windows specific question.

According to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues),

> The system maintains a single system message queue and one thread-specific message queue for each GUI thread. To avoid the overhead of creating a message queue for non–GUI threads, **all threads are created initially without a message queue**. The system creates a thread-specific message queue only when the thread makes its first call to one of the specific user functions; no GUI function calls result in the creation of a message queue.

So far I believed on that all threads are created initially without a message queue. Today, I tested this with [PostThreadMessageW](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postthreadmessagew) because it is stated that

> The function fails if the specified thread does not have a message queue.

However, PostThreadMessageW always returns 1 (TRUE) for all threads right after creation.

```
DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
BOOL bResult = PostThreadMessageW(dwThreadID, WM_QUIT, 123, 456);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The docs are a bit vague on what the set of "specific user functions" actually is. But if `PostThreadMessage` is *one of those functions*, then of course a thread calling that function and sending a message to itself will always succeed.

Comment: Oh that is convincing. But doesn't that mean "The function fails if the specified thread does not have a message queue." is wrong description as far as it creates message queue instead of returning fail?

Comment: You're looking at an odd condition. The doc is correct in general. Posting messages to *your own thread* is an unusual situation so I wouldn't expect the docs to devote much time considering that edge case.

Comment: The doc specify that the **thread to which message is posted** must have created a queue. To which thread are you posting? Does have that thread called any message handling function? (I.e. `PeekMessage`, `GetMessage()` or `WaitMessage()`).

Comment: Posting messages at your own thread works because they are so called **nonqueued messages**.

Comment: The newly created thread calls PostThreadMessage to own thread after entering LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE.

Comment: I just tested calling PostThreadMessageW from different thread and it returned 0 (FALSE). So PostThreadMessage works differently to which the thread message is posted? If the posting thread and the thread being posted are same (posting to own thread), the message is processed as non queued messages, as if the message is sent by SendMessage rather than posted. If the posting thread and the thread being posted are different, PostThreadMessage posts the message and shows the behavior of returning fail as stated. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Exactly what I asserted above. You're correct. Posting to its own thread call directly the handler bypassing the queing.

Comment: Thank you so much Frankie_C and Damien_The_Unbeliever!

Comment: @fra That's wrong, literally everything. **Posting** a message to the current thread creates an entry in the message queue for the current thread. It will not, ever, directly call into the window procedure associated with the receiver (there isn't even a window involved when calling `PostThreadMessage`). Those are *queued* messages. Always. Things are different when **sending** messages. But noone is sending messages here.

Comment: @IInspectable. You're right, I made some confusion with windows messages handling. In this case the behavior is simply explained deducting that the `PostThreadMessage()` create a queue in the calling thread, so it is successful posting in the same thread and failing when posting in another thread that doesn't have a queue. Anyway thread messages should be the same as windows one except for the window handle that is NULL.

Comment: @fra No. Thread messages are *very* different from window messages. See [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553) for details, and why `WM_NULL` is the only meaningful message you can post to a thread that potentially shows a UI. Also: [Thread messages are eaten by modal loops](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783).

Comment: Using `PostThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_NULL, 0, 0)` is a very common way to have a new thread create a message queue for itself before entering its message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the links. I have read them carefully. They seems to confirm my knowledge about the message subsystem that is standard vehiculation for system messages of any kind (window or thread). What Raymond Chen discuss in the articles is the loss of thread messages, specifically in UI threads, when retrieved in a window message pump loop. After the translation in the dispatching phase the message, already removed from the queue by `GetMessage()` is discarded by the `DispatchMessage()` that is unable to service any window due to the `NULL` value of associated window handle.

Comment: @IInspectable. He also points out that functions implementing local message pumps (modal) can silently discard thread messages. @RemyLebeau confirmed the behavior that `PostThreadMessage()` creates a message queue in the thread where it is invoked. This should be obvious anyway because to retrieve messages from a queue the last should exist.

Comment: `PostThreadMessage` can't just put message into another thread's queue.
It has to coordinate this action with system and other thread. Probably to do so it uses some parts of messaging system and initializes it (and its queue too).